# Excel Sumifs multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

i have a datasheet where (B) column is the furniture description list and (E) column is the stock quantity list. so I want the sum of the column that contained "BED" text (E5) in B column but at the same time should not contain the "SIDE" text (E1) within each column.

I tried to research for right formula but nothing is working, I tried already the following:

=SUMIFS('Stock Balance'!$E:$E,'Stock Balance'!$B:$B,""&E5&"",'Stock Description'!$B:$B,"<>E1")

not working accurately. also, I tried

=SUMIFS('Stock Balance'!$E:$E,'Stock Balance'!$B:$B,""&E5&"",'Stock Discription'!$B:$B,"<>"&E1)

also not working accurately.

Comment: Why are your sum and criteria ranges on different sheets? `'Stock Balance'!$E:$E` and `Stock Description'!$B:$B`?

Comment: =SUMIFS('Stock Balance'!$E4:$E5000,'Stock Balance'!$B4:$B5000,"*"&E5&"*",'Stock Balance'!$B4:$B5000,"<>"&"*"&E1&"*") and this also did not give me the accurate answer the result in this formula is 33 and when I check it manually it should be only 18 ? 

sorry my mistake, its actually in the same sheet

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result, and the incorrect result when using that formula.

Comment: i need your support please to make it work

Comment: Description / =G4:G13
1-Bedcover - 240x270cms - Classic Quilted - 
2-Bedcover - 240x270cms - Classic Quilted - 
3-OSAKA Bed - 240x230x86cms - Ashwood - 
4-ADDU WavyBed w.luxury slats-194x219x140cms-Natural - 
5-SHABBY BED - Mattress: 180x200 - Buff Bur. Nutmeg - 
6-AGREST Bed Side Table-69x44x50xcms-WALNT/CERMIC - 
7-DRAMMEN King Bed -MttrsSize:180x200cms- White - 
8-DRAMMEN BEDSIDE -60x40x60cms- Whitewash - 
9-Artus 4 Poster Bed -MttrsSize180x200- Light Brown -

Comment: Total Stock / =H4:H13 - 
4
5
1
1
1
2
1
2
1

Comment: ''side'' =I3 - ''bed'' =I2 - the furmula i used here is =SUMIFS(H5:H13,G5:G13,"*"&I2&"*",G5:G13,"<>"&"*"&I3&"*")

Comment: the result is = 14 while the actual answear is = 5 supost to be

Comment: @Majid please use this as a guide in the future https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The data you posted in the comments is not accurate either-- you list 9 pieces of data and have a range of 10. Further the desired results do not match the data you give-- only items 6 and 8 in the description contains "side" and both item 6 and 8 contain the string "bed". So the result would be 0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"<>*E1*"` the last condition should be `"<>"&"*"&E1&"*"`. So in total `=SUMIFS('Stock Balance'!$E:$E,'Stock Description'!$B:$B,"*"&E5&"*",'Stock Description'!$B:$B,"<>"&"*"&E1&"*")` should work.

Note that it is generally best to reduce the ranges (e.g. E1:E100 instead of E:E). Also see BigBen's comment, it is probably unlikely the sum range and criteria range are on different pages.